# Is there any way to interprite LaTeX math input in SciPy?

Tags: python, parsing, math, scipy, latex

I wonder how to parse LaTex math input in SciPy such as vectors and matrices with math operations inside?

for example having devlaved variables a, b and functions F(t), D(x) in my python code I want to be able to parse LaTex equations as input

```
$$
s_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}F{}t*D{}5 & 2\\
3 & -t +a*b \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

[image]

Something similar can be acheived with [this C++ based solution](http://goo.gl/LBCDjq). Yet SciPy privides utilities for solving DE systems numerically which I require. So I wonder if it provides facilities to interprit LaTeX input (or how to interprite it in some other compatible Python library)?

Comment: *"Yet SciPy privides utilities for solving DE systems numerically which I require. So I wonder if it provides facilities to interprit LaTeX input..."*  It does not.